# What does mask 0.0.0.0 mean when it's assigned to a network interface?

Tags: networking, network-interface, netmask

Suppose I use ifconfig or some similar command to setup my network interface, and I assign 0.0.0.0 to the mask parameter. Does it have a special meaning? What implications could this have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0.0.0.0 generally means that the network interface isn't bound to any network at all, not even localhost requests will be acknowledged. If anything it's a way of the operating system to present the interface as available but inactive and un-routed.

Comment: Would ARP Request from the host owning said interface work?

Comment: I don't think it would, it doesn't in Windows in any case.

Answer (score 3):

From [ArsTechnica](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=281922):

> Think of a subnet mask as a filter for outbound traffic. The subnet
>   mask helps the IP protocol decide which is local "LAN" traffic and
>   what traffic needs to be forwarded to a router.
>
> In effect a 0.0.0.0 subnet mask would make it so all outbound traffic
>   is 'local' and nothing will ever be forwarded to a router. This
>   configuration should work fine if there is no router (aka Default
>   Gateway) on the network.
>
> If you do need to route you can always add static routes on the house
>   by using the ROUTE ADD command (Windows, other OS's should have the
>   same/similar command).

In this case (with a few edits for brevity). I can add a /0 or 0.0.0.0 netmask to an interface, and it will work on loopback and link-local:

```
root@host:/tmp# ip addr add 10.0.0.0/0 dev eth0
root@host:/tmp# ip addr show
root@host:/tmp# ip a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> ...
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> ...
    link/ether fe:dc:ba:98:76:54 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.0/0 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> ...
    link/ether 01:23:45:67:89:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.5/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::226:c6ff:fe4b:e38e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@host:/tmp# ping 10.0.0.0
PING 10.0.0.0 (10.0.0.0) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.0: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.0: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.0 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.033/0.034/0.036/0.006 ms
```